# How to wrap c++ into objective-c and link it to swift package?

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, linkage, swift-package-manager

Hope someone can help me. 
I am trying to build swift package for Swift Package Manager. I want to include some C++ source in it and operate with it with all advantages of OOP. So I created new package and added three modules: one for execution swift in package("swift-exec"), second for my c++ lib("cppLib") and third for objective-c wrapper of the c++ lib("cwrapper").

**Package Description:**

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Objc",
    targets: [Target(name: "cwrapper", dependencies:["cpplib"]),
              Target(name: "swift-exec", dependencies:["cwrapper"]),
    ]
)
```

**My C++ Lib:**

cpplib.cpp :

```
#import "include/cpplib.h"

A::A(int _i) : m_Int(_i) {}
int A::getInt() { return m_Int ; }
```

cpplib.h :

```
class A {
public:
    A(int);
    int getInt();
private:
    int m_Int;

};
```

**My Wrapper:**

cwrapper.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Wrapper : NSObject

-(instancetype)initWithNum:(NSInteger)num;
- (NSInteger)getIntFromObject;

@end
```

cwrapper.**mm**

```
#import "include/cwrapper.h"
#import "cpplib.h"

@interface Wrapper()

@property (nonatomic, readonly) A* internal;
@end

@implementation Wrapper

-(instancetype)initWithNum:(NSInteger) num {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        _internal = new A((int)num);

    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)getIntFromObject {
    return (NSInteger)self.internal->getInt();
}

- (void)dealloc {
    delete _internal;
}
@end
```

**My Swift Execution:**

main.swift :

```
import cwrapper

let object = Wrapper.init(num: 54)
guard let object = object  else {
    exit(-1)
}
print("\(object.getIntFromObject())")
```

When I am building my project in Xcode I have no errors, my project successfully building, linking and running. But when I try to build package with command "**swift build**" I am getting error:

```
$ swift build
Linking cwrapper
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Wrapper in cwrapper.mm.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Wrapper in cwrapper.mm.o
  "__objc_empty_cache", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Wrapper in cwrapper.mm.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Wrapper in cwrapper.mm.o
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      -[Wrapper getIntFromObject] in cwrapper.mm.o
  "_objc_msgSendSuper2", referenced from:
      -[Wrapper initWithNum:] in cwrapper.mm.o
      -[Wrapper dealloc] in cwrapper.mm.o
  "_objc_retain", referenced from:
      -[Wrapper initWithNum:] in cwrapper.mm.o
  "_objc_storeStrong", referenced from:
      -[Wrapper initWithNum:] in cwrapper.mm.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /path/to/DEV/playground/swpackage/.build/debug.yaml
```

So my question is: is it possible to do what I am trying to do? To wrap c++ to objc and link it to swift package?

If yes, what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: After some research I found that when Xcode trying to link .mm file it uses command

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
```

But when I am trying to do it in console, "swift build" uses that:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
```

Comment: Don't post errors as a screenshot. Post them as text.

Comment: Could you please post a link to this sample project to have a look?

Comment: @shallowThought sample project package: https://github.com/killann/SampleCPPWrapperProject

Comment: Please add the Xcode project and readme with the exact `swift build` instructions. (How exactly do you call it, params, and in which directory).

Comment: @shallowThought in root directory of repository, to generate Xcode project file I am using next command: "$ swift package generate-xcodeproj". For building in console in same directory I use "$ swift build".

Comment: I get `error: these referenced modules could not be found: objcwrapper`

Comment: @shallowThought be sure you on last commit, please. About a hour ago I updated Package.swift and fixed it.